# Jmeter Multiple Running Thread Group

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

Is there a property file in Jmeter that configures how many thread groups can run concurrently. I have a test case where if I run 5 thread groups, the test is successful but the moment I add a 6th thread group, one of the thread group fails. Is there a limit to no of thread groups we can run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined limit of thread groups, however JMeter may fail to kick off some **threads** if it lacks resources so make sure you are:

- [Following JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [Tune JMeter for maximum performance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)
- Set up monitoring on your load generator(s) using operating system built-in tools or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)

Once done gradually increase the amount of active threads (virtual users) and at the same time monitor baseline OS health metrics and JVM and GC behaviour. Once you hit the limits of a single host - this would be maximum amount of threads you will be able to start. If it is not enough to fulfil your load testing requirements you will need to go for [distributed testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)